# JSONPath: how to get empty string (or null) if path (field) not exist?

Tags: php, json, jsonpath

Incoming JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Name1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Name2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Name3",
    "surname": "Surname3"
  }
]
```

If we use JSONPath like `$[:].name`, we will receive:

```json
[
  0: "Name1",
  1: "Name2",
  2: "Name3"
]
```

But if will use the same to get `surname` (`$[:].surname`), we will receive:

```json
[
  0: "Surname3"
]
```

Is this possible to get surname values with empty string (or nulls) to keep right indexes? E.g.

```json
[
  0: "",
  1: "",
  2: "Surname3"
]
```

P.S.: at the moment I'm using [this library](https://github.com/SoftCreatR/JSONPath).

Answer (score 2):

JSON Path doesn't support returning placeholder values like that.  It's a query language for JSON documents, much like SQL is for relational databases.  Could you imagine if a SQL query returned placeholder values for every record in a database that didn't match your query?

I expect that the reason you want this is to determine where in the original document the value appears.  To that end, JSON Path implementations *should* support returning the paths to the values instead of the values themselves:

```json
[
  "$[2]['surname']"
]
```

But I can't see in the README of that library where such a feature is supported (though it still might).